# REGEX in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I won't found data from table who start following by CR and one space and 4 to 6 number

Query

```
SELECT `order_det_ref_no` FROM `manufacturers_order` WHERE
`order_det_ref_no` REGEXP '%^CR\s+\b\w{4,6}$%'
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL regex does not use regex delimiters, nor does it support `\b` (it uses `[[:<:]]` for a word start position and `[[:>:]]` for a word end), `\s`, `\w` regex shorthand classes. Use

```
REGEXP '^CR[[:space:]]+[[:alnum:]_]{4,6}$'
```

Note that `[[:space:]]` matches both horizontal and vertical whitespace, you may use `[[:blank:]]` if you also need to only match horizontal whitespace.

Comment: Thank you, sir, its working can you give me more detail about REGEXP in mysql query

Comment: Yes, see [Syntax of MySQL Regular Expressions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp). The point is that it only supports a sort of POSIX regex flavor that is extremely limited in available features, but is really fast.

Comment: Sstr have random value like $str="CR | CM | EL | AD"; how can i add php varibale in regexp   REGEXP '^**$str**[[:space:]]+[[:alnum:]_]{4,6}$'

Comment: Usually, in PHP, you may concatenate strings with `.` operator. Grouping in MySQL regex can be done with `(....)`. Also, make sure there are no spaces around `|`, they will prevent matches. It should look like `'^(' . str_replace(' | ', '|', $str) . ')[[:space:]]+[[:alnum:]_]{4,6}$'`